# How to execute a string as a variable within a function or a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Lets say I have the following function

```
def code_string(a):
    for i in range(a):
        exec('f=a+i')
        print(f)
```

When I run it in the using the following command

```
code_string(3)
```

It gives me the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-9c91de8067f3> in <module>()
----> 1 code_string(3)

<ipython-input-2-2ae9915b0a25> in code_string(a)
      2     for i in range(a):
      3         exec('f=a+i')
----> 4         print(f)

NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

when I run it not in the function as so

```
a=3
for i in range(a):
    exec('f=a+i')
    print(f)
```

It works perfectly fine as so

```
3
4
5
```

Why is this happening and can I execute a string code within a function in python

NOTE: This is only a demo example, please do not expect my code to be as simple as this demo example. I just put it to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def code_string(a):
    for i in range(a):
        exec('f=a+i', locals(), globals())
        print(f)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it worked but why it is important to mention locals and globals?